# How to Import module based on a condition in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spartacus-storefront

I am creating a module for Search integration. instead of directly importing the SearchModule inside app.module.ts file, i want to call an API and import the SearchModule based on the API response.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    **SearchModule**
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Please suggest an approach.

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible with an API call, but you could do it like this:
`Statement ? SearchModule : []`.

Comment: you can build modules dynamically, but you better not to do that, because you will have to inclide angular compiler into the bundle. what is insinde of a search module? maybe you could describe specifics of your problem and SO community will help you to resolve it with other means, for example using of DI

Answer (score 0):

you could use different routes, depending on your condition and use the lazy loading based on routing handle it.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules